# Are there any dangers to editing a membership type directly in the database?

Tags: civimember, relationships

We have a membership type that is shared by relationship. However, after the membership type was created, we needed to share it by a new relationship type. I edited the membership type directly in the database to add the new relationship type (since the interface does not allow you to edit that after a membership is created). I simply added the new **relationship_type_id** and **relationship_direction** in the **civicrm_membership_type** table for the appropriate row.

It seems to have been working fine, but I am tracking down a bug now and wonder if this edit may be related. (The bug does not seem to happen on the demo site).

Here's the issue: when a relationship is disabled from the Organization or Individual's Relationship tab (ie. using the "**more > Disable**" command rather than editing the relationship, disabling, and saving) the membership which is shared by relationship is not disabled. When the relationship is rather edited by clicking **Edit**, unchecking **Enabled**, and saving, the membership disappears as expected. (In fact, if I do it the first way, then **Edit** and **Save** without changing anything, the membership disappears, too.)

UPDATE: I can actually reproduce this on the demo server with a non-Employee relationship so I think it may be a bug. I [have submitted a bug ticket on JIRA](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16306).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updating via DB should be fine, note that it won't update existing membership records to create inherited memberships.

Issue mentioned related to **Disable** might be a bug. I would suggest filing an issue in bug tracker if you are able to replicate it on the demo.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to reproduce with a non-Employee relationship (Employee relationship works as expected). Bug ticket updated/linked above.